I need to simulate a realsense depth camera in gazebo ignition fortress & connect it with ros 2 humble hawksbill. I can't find any resources for it
Every relevant resource that I was able to find so far seems to be intended for either gazebo classic 11 or ros 1 noetic ninjemys. As far as I understand, there are significant differences between newer & older versions. Just in case that I missed something mistakenly, I decided to ask about available resources here before trying to port setups from older to newer versions. My skills are still basic level, so please let me know in case I skipped something important.

What have you tried and what didn't work?

@Greenonline I'm creating a port of the realsense depth camera for my versions of gazebo & ros because it seems that there's no better option.

what is your question about the available resources?

@jsotola the one answer that i received so far has my resolved issues just enough for me to continue my work, as i simply wanted to know whether i needed to port the plugin or not)

I was able to find some virtual intel realsense camera models, that i can use after improving them a bit, through the gazebo sim app website (formerly known as the gazebo ignition fuel website). They're not completely ready for use on their own but it made my work much easier. I'm sharing a link that leads to search results for intel realsense device models just in case others need it later.

You are correct there are no official resources for the intel realsense camera, Intel did have a repository but no longer maintains it: https://github.com/intel/gazebo-realsense
You also are correct that there are significant differences between Gazebo Classic and Gazebo
Available resources:
https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/ros2/ros_gz_sim_demos
ros_gz_sim_demos provides some good demos with rgb and rgbd cameras that you can reference
Here is another example from gz-rendering documentation: https://gazebosim.org/api/rendering/8/depth_camera.html
However, if the project you are working on does not need long term support, it may make sense to use gazebo classic and follow the example shown in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpUCG6K5muI&t=314s

Oh. I understand now! I think that it's better for me to create my own implementation based on the available resources. The software versions in my current project are decided by my supervisor, so it's best for me to stick to them.
